# SharePoint 2013 Asset Library, view counter missing in the videoplayerpage.aspx

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sitepages, video, asset-library

I have customized the `videoplayerpage.aspx` by adding star ratings (which works).

Unfortunately the view counter is missing even it's in the source code of the page:

```
<div class="ms-displayInlineBlock">
<div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_idVideoSetViewCountContainer" style="display:none;">
    &#160;&#160;<span class="ms-soften">|</span>&#160;&#160;
<div class="ms-displayInlineBlock">
<span>Vues :</span></div>
<div class="ms-displayInlineBlock">
<span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_idVideoSetViewCount">0</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The layer `ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_idVideoSetViewCountContainer` is hidden and the counter is always equal to zero (even if there are several ratings).

I tried to re index the asset library but that didn't work either.

Any idea to fix this?